# Magnolia CkEditor InternalLink not listed in toolbar

Tags: ckeditor, magnolia

I'm using Magnolia 6 with the installed CKEDITOR and want to customize the toolbar.

In my case, the definition for the Field looks like:

```
name: text
class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.RichTextFieldDefinition
label: Text
configJsFile: "/.resources/editor_config.js"
```

The `editor_config.js` contains the following:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.toolbar = "Magnolia";
    config.toolbar_Magnolia =  [
        { name: "basicstyles", items: ["Bold", "Italic", "Subscript", "Superscript", "SpecialChar"] },
        { name: "links",    items: [ "Link", "InternalLink", "DamLink", "Unlink" ] }
    ];
};
```

Now  i open the editor and doesn't see the field `InternalLink` in the Toolbar.

But the configuration looks correct. Without my custom configuration field, there is the InternalLink button in the Toolbar.

Do i forget something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing

`config.extraPlugins = "magnolialink,magnoliaFileBrowser";`

Usually I get magnolia default configuration and continue with customization from there

***magnolia-ui-framework/src/main/resources/mgnl-resources/ckeditor/config-magnolia.js***